Installing hardwood floors over concrete slab with a finished room underneath
I would like to install hardwood floors on a concrete slab using an adhesive that is also rated as a vapor barrier.  Below the slab is a finished room.
From what I read in the installation manual, I can glue the wood planks down to the subfloor.  While the installation manual advises using plywood as the subfloor, it does not say why.  I could guess that it could be that plywood might be flatter than concrete, but both are permeable to moisture.
The adhesive that I would be using would be also acting as a vapor barrier.  Following the installation instructions for spacing from the wall and gluing the tongue and groove joints, is this a bad idea to attempt?  Will I have problems in a year, 5 years, etc.?  The last thing I'd want is for my nice wood floor to start buckling due to moisture issues that could have been easily prevented.
I realize that glue is permanent and would make removal extremely difficult.  I am still contemplating if that makes sense - for what it is worth, I have had hardwood floors for the past 15 years and don't foresee the need or desire to replace those, but I have the option.  With these being glued down and glued together, it will be a battle to remove them.
If I cannot solely rely on the adhesive acting as a vapor barrier, then what if I glue down felt paper and then glue the wood to the felt paper?
I must limit total floor height to 1.25-in as my contractor had installed the exterior door directly on the concrete and did not raise it up at all even though there was space to do so.  Therefore, I think I'm limited to how high the floor can be because the door won't open if it is too high.  I am saying 1.25-in as that is the height from the concrete to the top of the door jamb.  If the floor or door aren't exactly level or plumb, then that number will be smaller.  With 3/4-in flooring, that leaves me 1/2-in to work with to attempt to use quarter-round, but will probably have to make a custom trim piece for it to fit.
I do not run the HVAC that often, only whenever the heat is unbearable or it is cold outside.  As a result, the humidity fluctuates quite a bit.
With that in mind, what can I do to ensure I have hardwood floors to enjoy for many years to come?
I called the flooring adhesive manufacturer and flooring manufacturer and both recommend the room be climate controlled as you suggest otherwise the floors may cup, the adhesive may fail, etc.
I came across This Old House and perhaps if I am adamant about doing hardwood, I float the floor.
It is for engineered and I have a solid hardwood floor, but can I float a hardwood floor?

how about a paint-on floor sealer  before the glue?

Check the slab for flatness with a long straight edge.  Seeing much more than a dime/nickle depth of light between the floor and straight edge needs more checking/fixing.

Yes, I have some dips larger than a dime / nickle.  How should I fix those, 15 lb felt paper?  if I'm gluing to concrete, do I glue down the felt paper?

You say below the slab is a finished room. You don't need a vapor barrier.
In my area (Fl.) wood flooring is glued to cement slabs quite often. This is done with no other sealer or barrier applied to the concrete, and I'm talking about slab on grade concrete. The vapor barrier placed prior to the concrete pour is the only vapor protection.  With a finished room under the slab, the air should be conditioned and there is obviously no ground water issue.

I agree with you, but don't want to find out the hard way.  Yes, both rooms will be conditioned, but we generally leave our windows open unless it is < 55F or > 80F.  If I have some dips that are about 3/16-in tall, can I use the flooring adhesive to compensate for that?

If the adhesive is layed out with a 1/4" notched trowel , you should be ok with minor variations.

Thanks - I still plan to call the mfr regarding moisture and concrete.  if they advise, should I glue down felt paper, or roll on a vapor barrier, then glue to that?

It would be best to follow their recommendations.  However, in my experience, felt paper  was never used in a glue down installation.

One other question, as I mentioned, I attempted to use self-leveling compound.  I thought I mixed it fairly well, but in some spots, it is fairly smooth, and others it is fairly rough.  It seems it is attached well to the concrete below, but I can scrape off a thin layer with a little bit of force whereas if I do that on solid concrete, I would not be getting dust. It's been there for about a week.  Would you advise removing the self-leveling compound I put down?

No, leave the self leveling alone.

If we don't have the HVAC system running all the time, would that change your advice to gluing down the floor?  We only tend to run it when it is either excessively hot or cold.  As a result, the humidity would also fluctuate a bit.  The house has quite a bit of thermal inertia, so the max temperature difference is no more than 20-F (no less than 60F and no more than 80F) over the course of the year.  The rest of the house has hardwood floors and they're fine, but when they were refinished, the contractor puttied the gaps and the putty is coming loose.

not using the AC will cause the humidity to be higher. This is humidity in the air. It has nothing to do with the level of moisture in a slab, which is what a vapor barrier controls.  So you still don't need a vapor barrier.  The higher humidity will make the wood more susceptible to swelling.  This is why you're seeing the putty come loose. My advice does not change for your AC usage, other than maybe wood flooring is not your best choice for your lifestyle.

I updated the question to also ask for guidance on additional things I can do under these conditions.  Perhaps that means I do a floating floor installation?  Or, perhaps I don't install hardwood unless I condition the room.
